# Identify this plant please

Tags: identification

This has large leaves that wilt and brown after blooming in early spring. It resembles a hosta but not as attractive. The flowers are pink on a tall stem. The flowers resemble a phlox.[image]

Comment: These are good plants for shady, damp areas - as you've discovered, they tend to wilt and go brown in sunnier more exposed situations because they dry out too much. Sun exposure is fine IF the soil remains moist.

Answer (score 4):

That’s a [bergenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergenia).

The perennial plant forms thick rhizomes and is typically frost-hardy.